# How to exclude files in rsync?

Tags: server, backup, rsync

I'm using ubuntu server 12.04, now I want to backup some files using rsync, here is a try:

```
rsync -aAX $HOME/Documents/* $HOME/Backups/TEST --exclude={$HOME/Documents/another/*,$HOME/Documents/temp/*}
```

As you can see, I want to backup all files in the folder *$HOME/Documents* to folder *$HOME/Backups/TEST*, but ***exclude*** files in folder **another** and **temp**. But I failed, rsync still copied the files in both excluded folders:

```
ls $HOME/Backups/TEST/another
test
```

***test*** is a file in the folder ***another***, and it is also copied though I exclude the file in rsync, why? How to let those files be actually excluded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several issues with your rsync command (also see [manpage for rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/rsync.1.html) for detailed explanation of filter rules).

- we need an `--exclude` command each for any given pattern.
- paths given need to be relative to the source path (no absolute paths).
- options need to be given before we state source and destination.

For your example the following syntax will work:

```
rsync -avAX --exclude=another/ --exclude=temp/ ~/Documents/ ~/Backups/TEST
```

Note that if an exlude pattern ends with `/` it refers to a directory. If you omit it both, files and directories with that name will be excluded. Replace it with a wildcard `*` to exclude all files or directories with that string in their names.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. I'm not sure how it works, but from experimentation, `--exclude=/foo` will exclude the directory `foo` directly in the source, but `--exclude=foo` will exclude any directories named foo, even in subdirectories.

Answer (score 12):

You may find it easier to add `.rsync-filter` files in your source directories, and use the `-F` option.

From the man page:

> -F : The  -F  option is a shorthand [...] for this rule:
>
> ```
>  --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'
> ```
>
> This tells rsync to look for per-directory .rsync-filter files
>   that have been sprinkled through the hierarchy and use their
>   rules to filter the files in the transfer.

For example: in $HOME/Documents/.rsync-filter

```
# you can add comments in filter files

- /another/
- /temp/
```

Instead of `-`, you can also write the whole word `exclude`.

Now you can

```
rsync -aAX -F $HOME/Documents/ $HOME/Backups/TEST/
```